# Change trade direction when trade price is reached

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I would like to change the trade direction when the price in the chart returns to the level I entered the last trade.
Therefore, if I went long at $12,300, I want to change the trade direction to short once the price gets back to that level.
This is what I have implemented so far:

```
// Go Long
if trade_short == true and close >= trade_preis_short 

    alert("LL_Korrektur Long " + str.tostring(tick), alert.freq_once_per_bar)  // , freq = alert.freq_all   alert.freq_once_per_bar
    //show_long := true
    //show_short := false

    trade_long := true
    trade_short := false

    sperr_trade_long := sperr_trade_long + 1
    sperr_trade_short := 0
    //numm_trade := 1

    trade_preis_long := low
    trade_preis_short := 0

    stopp_loss_long := low - stopp_loss_betrag
    //stopp_line_long := line.new(bar_index - 1, stopp_loss_long, bar_index + 1, stopp_loss_long, color = color.rgb(170, 243, 102, 10), width = 4)

    // Tradepreis Linie zeichenen
    line.new(bar_index - 1, trade_preis_long, bar_index + 1, trade_preis_long, color = color.rgb(243, 85, 243, 10), width = 4)


// Go short
if trade_long == true and close <= trade_preis_long 

    alert("SS_Korrektur Short " + str.tostring(tick), alert.freq_once_per_bar)  // , freq = alert.freq_all   alert.freq_once_per_bar
    //show_short := true
    //show_long := false

    trade_short := true
    trade_long := false


    sperr_trade_short := sperr_trade_short + 1
    sperr_trade_long := 0
    //numm_trade := 6

    trade_preis_short := high
    trade_preis_long := 0

    stopp_loss_short := high + stopp_loss_betrag
    //stopp_line_short := line.new(bar_index - 1, stopp_loss_short, bar_index + 1, stopp_loss_short, color = color.rgb(170, 243, 102, 10), width = 4)

    // Tradepreis Linie zeichenen
    line.new(bar_index - 1, trade_preis_short, bar_index + 1, trade_preis_short, color = color.rgb(21, 247, 122, 10), width = 4)
```

But since the price jumps back and forth several times when the candle is created, I don't want to change the trading direction several times in one candle.
How can I make it so that the function only occurs when the last candle is in the past. Therefore my trade value e.g. $12,300 was created in a past candle?